# Cannot push local repository to remote Bitbucket

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

I have configured a local bit repository and have several test commits with files in it.Status is available as follows.

[image]

I have a Bitbucket account and created a new repository and I have given the link of it.
[image]

Then I tried to push the content of local git to remote repository in Bitbucket. But I get an error message. 
[image]

How to get this sorted? Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Comment: you need to use `git pull -u origin master` first. then commit again and try push

Comment: you don't have the last version of the branch. Do `git pull origin master` first

Comment: Please don’t post screen shots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have to fetch first the changes from the remote repository and the push

again.

```
  git fetch origin master
  git checkout master
```

Take a look here https://blog.plover.com/prog/git-ff-error.html

Answer (score 1):

If I read the error message correctly, it looks like there are commit(s) on the remote branch which you don't have locally.  Try pulling first:

```
git pull -u origin master
```

Then try your push:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these commands.

```
git add .
git commit -m "your commit message"
git push -u origin master.
```

if any changes were not pulled initially u need to pull first

```
git pull -u origin master
```